# how to properly generate html for django modelform

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to place div around group of form fields in django template.
Easiest way would be to do is

**MyForm().as_table()**

copypaste that and enclose group of fields with appropriate div. Only problem is that this approach fails when there are errors in form validation because  **{{ form.fieldname.errors }}** isn't mentioned anywhere.

Any better ideas or readymade tools that would save me from doing this by hand every time?

here is answer if anyone needs it

```
def generate_object_template(object):
    from string import Template
    for field in object._meta.fields:
            t = Template(""" <label>{{ form.$fieldname.label }}{% if form.$fieldname.is_required %}*{% endif %}</label>
             {{ form.$fieldname }}
             {% if form.$fieldname.errors %} {{ form.$fieldname.errors }}{% endif %}""").substitute(fieldname=field.attname)                                  
            print t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to customize a form in Django you can do as follow

```
 ...
 <label>{{ form.myfield.label }}{% if form.myfield.is_required %}*{% endif %}</label>
 {{ form.myfield }}
 {% if form.myfield.errors %} {{ form.myfield.errors }}{% endif %}

<label>{{ form.myfield3.label }}{% if form.myfield3.is_required %}*{% endif %}</label>
 {{ form.myfield3 }}
 {% if form.myfield3.errors %} {{ form.myfield3.errors }}{% endif %}

 <label>{{ form.myfield2.label }}{% if form.myfield2.is_required %}*{% endif %}</label>
 {{ form.myfield2 }}
 {% if form.myfield2.errors %} {{ form.myfield2.errors }}{% endif %}
...
```

With this kind of set up you can customize your form adding div where you want and still keep the validation on.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Comment: what you wrote doesn't allow me to put div around element 3,4,5, just around all elements or single element

Comment: ok remove the {% for loop %} I made a mistake dont use the for loop just put your flat fields

Comment: I never understood the inflexibility here.  This is my biggest (albeit still small) gripe with Django.  I also make a special "form loop" with variables that let me do things like headings, special labels, etc.